# Passing data form datatable to modal django

Tags: python, ajax, django, bootstrap-modal

I want to display data from datatable to modal bootstrap.

Example:

```
Name    | prenom | id |edit
example | test   |  2 |button edit
```

Button will send data to modal to display for update.

Button code:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-form="{% url 'up' id=val.id }" data-target="#myEdit" >Edit</a>
```

Modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myEdit" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form  class="well contact-form" method="post" action="{% url 
      'up'}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label for="usr">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" name="uss" value="{{ instance.name }}" id="uss">
                    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                    <input  type="password"  class="form-control" required="" value="{{ instance.sname }}" name="pwd" id="pwd" >
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Valider</button>
                    <button  value="" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def posts_edit(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(namemodel, id=id)
    context={
        'instance': instance
    }
    return render(request, '/ges/sortie/', context)
```

I want to display two values `Name` and `prenom` in modal, the data show it from database.

I think the best solution is using ajax.

Comment: I don't think I understood what you are trying to achieve. Do you want that when user clicks on 'edit' button the modal open up and show the form filled with the data?

Comment: yeah bro that is exactly what i need hhhh

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your modal code contains a `form`, but you are asking how to display some data, so it leaves me a bit confusing what you really want to do. Please be more clear.

I am going to suppose you want to show some data on a `modal`, and that data should be retrieved from the server using AJAX.

There are several ways to do this. Let me explain you two general options:

## **1. Server processed HTML**

In your initial template you just have an empty `div` which you can update with HTML code.

Everytime you want show some data, you do an AJAX request **which will return HTML code** (in this case the `modal` HTML code) and you just insert it on your `div`.

## **2. Client processed HTML**

In your initial template you may have a skeleton of your HTML code (in this case the `modal` HTML skeleton), and through javascript you can update some values on it.

Everytime you want to show some data, you do an AJAX request **which may return JSON data** and using that information you update the values in the HTML skeleton.

---

## Differences

Using the first one implies writing more code in the backend (the Django template in this case) while the latter encourages you to write more javascript code in the frontend.

As rendering the template on server side is quite slow and the transfered data is also larger (all the HTML code usually contains more bytes than raw JSON data), the former option may be a bit slower. Anyway I believe that for this simple case such difference is not relevant.

---

## Code

As I prefer to work on the backend rather than writing too much javascript, the following solution will be an implementation of a *Server Processed HTML*. Here it is (you were pretty close btw):

Your main template:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Prenom</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ val.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ val.prenom }}</td>
      <td>{{ val.id }}</td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-info" class="open-modal" data-url="{% url 'up' id=val.id }">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Here we create this empty div for inserting modal -->
<div id="modal-div"></div>
```

Javacript in the main template:

```js
var modalDiv = $("#modal-div");

$(".open-modal").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
    success: function(data) {
      modalDiv.html(data);
      $("#myEdit").modal();
    }
  });
});
```

The important things here are that we have our button and a jQuery event that is triggered when someone clicks on it. The triggered function do the AJAX call, sets the returned HTML in the `modal-div` and finally opens the brand-new modal.

Your controller (Django view):

```py
def posts_edit(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(namemodel, id=id)
    context={
        'instance': instance
    }
    return render(request, 'modal.html', context)
```

Your modal template `modal.html`

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myEdit" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <form  class="well contact-form" method="post" action="{% url 'up'}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <label for="usr">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" name="uss" value="{{ instance.name }}" id="uss">
          <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <input  type="password"  class="form-control" required="" value="{{ instance.sname }}" name="pwd" id="pwd" >
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Valider</button>
          <button  value="" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much bro but a samll problem `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ges/3/update/` show me the data in inpute but modal doesn't show in really page that mean when i include modal.html

Comment: it's worked bro thank you so much just i add `type:'GET'` hhhhhhh thank you so much

Comment: jQuery `.ajax` uses `GET` method by default, so that shouldn't have been the problem. Anyway, I am glad to hear it worked for you!

Comment: Why do you have id=None and what is "up" in {% url 'up' %}? What would be the url in this case? I tried your solution but it didn't pull the modal. I must be missing something that is not indicated in the proposed solution. Also do you use the form.py for this or not?

Answer (score 0):

A good option is using the [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) framework to build components and fill your form dynamically.

I like very much Vue.js and I built an app to solve your problem.

I'll go step by step explaining what I did.

### 1. Let's simulate your objects with some data

*views.js*

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    users = [dict(id=1, first_name='Megan', last_name='Fox'),
             dict(id=2, first_name='Chester', last_name='Bennington')]
    if request.POST:
        for user in users:
            if user['id'] == int(request.POST.get('id')):
                user['first_name'] = request.POST.get('firstName')
                user['last_name'] = request.POST.get('lastName')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'users': users})
```

### 2. Import an EventBus built in Vue

We are going to need that event bus to show the modal. The event bus is the component which will "transport" events from one component to another. So we can listen and emit events globally.

*vue-bus.js*

```
const EventBus = new Vue();
Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    $bus: {
        get: function () {
            return EventBus;
        }
    }
});
```

### 3. Build a `row` component with Vue to show your data.

I changed your data to `firstName` and `lastName` to explain better.

This component renders your row with data and set up the edit button to emit the event `showModal` passing the data from the row.

*components/row.js*

```
Vue.component('row', {
    template: `
            <tr>
                <td>{{ firstName }}</td>
                <td>{{ lastName }}</td>
                <td>{{ id }}</td>
                <td><button @click="showModal">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
        `,
    props: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'id'],
    methods: {
        showModal: function() {
            this.$bus.$emit('showModal', this.firstName, this.lastName, this.id);
        }
    }
});
```

### 4. Build a `modal` component with Bootstrap

This component uses a `x-template` on *index.html* to render its contents. On this component all you need is a listener to the `showModal` event, so when the modal opens, it will be populated with the `row` content.

*components/modal.js*

```
Vue.component('modal', {
    template: '#modal-template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            id: 0
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.$bus.$on('showModal', function (firstName, lastName, id) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.id = id;
        }.bind(this));
    }
});
```

### 5. Build your Vue.js app

If you take a look at [Vue.js docs](https://vuejs.org/) you will see how it works. Basically, it will mount your application in the element with id `#app`.

Here I'm just listening to the `showModal` event, so when this event is emitted, the modal shows up.

*app.js*

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        showModal: false
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.$bus.$on('showModal', function () {
            this.showModal = true;
        }.bind(this));
    }
});
```

### 6. Some CSS to make it pretty

*css/styles.css*

```
table {
    margin: 20px;
}

td {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.modal-mask {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: table;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.modal-container {
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.modal-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}

.modal-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

### 7. Finally, the HTML

So, what I'm doing here is iterating over the users lists populating the rows with the user data.

The modal template is inside a `x-template` as I said before. You need to do some changes on Bootstrap modal to make this work like adding the class `show` and changing the `data-dismiss` attribute to close the modal.

The data is populated from the listener on *components/modal.js*. The bind is made on `:value`. See the `v-bind` documentation on Vue website to understand better how it works.

*index.html*

```
{% load static %}

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <table>
        {% for user in users %}
            <tr is="row" first-name="{{ user.first_name }}" last-name="{{ user.last_name }}" :id="{{ user.id }}"></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <modal v-show="showModal" @close="showModal = false"></modal>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
    <transition name="modal">
        <div class="modal-mask">
            <div class="modal-container">
                <div id="myModal" class="modal show" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <form method="post" action=".">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" @click="$emit('close')">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit User</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <label for="name">First Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" :value="firstName" />
                                    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" :value="lastName" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" :value="id" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="$emit('close')">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'vue-bus.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'components/row.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'components/modal.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## The Result

[image]

When we click on `Edit`:

[image]

Then we edit the data:

[image]

And save:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for answer bro but your code it's so hard i see it i think that @Martin it's better easy code