# Django Ajax get request - load model instance into a form

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django, ajaxform

I have a table in a HTML template that displays all instances of a django model. on each row of the template I have an edit button that looks up the primary key of each instance, and by clicking that button I want all the fields in the model instance to be populated in a modal by using ajax. After that I want to be able to edit the data and use ajax to send the edited data back to the database.

I have been searching all over the web and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310054/passing-data-form-datatable-to-modal-django) that is exactly what I need, but I still can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

jQuery code

```
var modalDiv = $("#modal-div");

$(".open-modal").on("click", function() {
console.log("button clicked");
var url = $(this).attr('data-url').replace('/', ''); 
console.log("url:",url); // this returns my customer number but is not used in the code below

$.ajax({
url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
type: 'get',
success: function(data) {
    console.log("success");
    modalDiv.html(data);
    $("#myEdit").modal(); //#myEdit is the ID of the modal

},
error : function() {

    console.log("Error: this did not work"); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
}
 });
});
```

a tag in form

```
<a class="btn open-modal" data-url="{% url 'dashboard:customer_update' kunde.kundenr %}">Edit</a>
```

Needless to say, I keep receiving the error console.log message. 
Below is the complete codebase.

Model:

```
class Kunde(models.Model):
avd = [('610','610'), ('615', '615'), ('620', '620'), ('625', '625'), '630', '630'), ('635', '635'),('640', '640'),('645', '645'), ('650', '650'), ('655', '655')]

avdeling = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=avd)
selskap = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
kundenr = models.CharField('Kundenummer', max_length=15, unique=True, primary_key=True)
gatenavn = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
postnr = models.CharField('Postnummer', max_length=4)
poststed = models.CharField(max_length=30)
kommune = models.CharField(max_length=30)
timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("dashboard:index")

def __str__(self):
    return self.selskap

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['selskap']
```

Urls

```
app_name = "dashboard" 
urlpatterns = [

path('', views.dashboard, name='index'),
path('', views.customer_list, name='customer_list'),
url(r'^(?P<kundenummer>[0-9]+)$', views.customer_update, name='customer_update'),
```

]

Views:
   main view to display the table

```
def dashboard(request):
template = 'dashboard/index.html'

if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Vest']).exists():
    queryset = Kunde.objects.filter(Q(avdeling='630') | Q(avdeling='635')).all()
elif request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Nord']).exists():
    queryset = Kunde.objects.filter(Q(avdeling='610') | Q(avdeling='615') | Q(avdeling='620')).all()
elif request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Øst']).exists():
    queryset = Kunde.objects.filter(Q(avdeling='660') | Q(avdeling='655') | Q(avdeling='650')).all()
elif request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Sør']).exists():
    queryset = Kunde.objects.filter(Q(avdeling='640') | Q(avdeling='645')).all()
elif request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Nord-Vest']).exists():
    queryset = Kunde.objects.filter(Q(avdeling='625')).all()
else:
    queryset = Kunde.objects.all()

context = {
    "object_list": queryset, 
    }

return render(request, template, context)
```

view to display the modal with

```
def customer_update(request, kundenr=None):
template = 'dashboard/index.html'
instance = get_object_or_404(Kunde, kundenr=kundenr)
context={
    'selskap': instance.selskap,
    'instance': instance,
}
return render(request, template, context)
```

HTML table

```
<div class"container-table" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                    <table class="display table table-bordered table-condensed"  id="table_kundeliste">
                        <thead class="thead-inverse">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Avdeling</th>
                                <th>Selskap</th>
                                <th>Kundenr.</th>
                                <th>Poststed</th>
                                <th>Kommune</th>
                                <th>Rediger</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for kunde in object_list %}
                            <tr>
                                <td> {{ kunde.avdeling }} </td>
                                <td> <a href="#">{{ kunde.selskap }}</a> </td>
                                <td> {{ kunde.kundenr }} </td>
                                <td> {{ kunde.poststed }} </td>
                                <td> {{ kunde.kommune }} </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn open-modal" data-url="{% url 'dashboard:customer_update' kunde.kundenr %}">Edit</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>    
                    </table>
                </div>
```

this part include modal in html

```
<div id="modal-div" class="modal-div">
     {% include 'dashboard/customer-modal.html' %}
</div>
```

this is the modal template itself

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myEdit" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<form  class="well contact-form" method="post" action="{% url dashboard:'customer_update'}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <label for="avdeling">Avdeling:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" name="avdeling" value="{{ instance.avdeling }}" id="avdeling">
      <label for="selskap">Selskap:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" name="selskap" value="{{ instance.selskap }}" id="selskap">
      <label for="kundenummer">Kundenummer:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" name="kundenummer" value="{{ instance.kundenr }}" id="kundenummer">
      <label for="gatenavn">Gatenavn:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" name="gatenavn" value="{{ instance.gatenavn }}" id="gatenavn">
      <label for="postnummer">Postnummer:</label>
      <input  type="text"  class="form-control" required="" value="{{ instance.postnr }}" name="postnummer" id="postnummer" >
      <label for="poststed">Poststed:</label>
      <input  type="text"  class="form-control" required="" value="{{ instance.poststed }}" name="poststed" id="poststed" >
      <label for="kommune">Kommune:</label>
      <input  type="text"  class="form-control" required="" value="{{ instance.kommune }}" name="kommune" id="kommune" >
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Valider</button>
      <button  value="" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```